React merges useState calls into a single render
I try to report to the user the progress of the promise execution. The problem I'm encountering is that React seems to be merging my setState calls into a single render.
When I click start, it flashes 0 / 5 and then stays 1 / 5, and other times it comes up higher than 1. There is also a problem with execution stopping when the button is pressed, because setState doesn't have time to update total and thus stops the code before the button is pressed (the commented line). The code below is my attempt.
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function ({}) {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ progress: 0, total: 0 });

  const wait = (duration) => () => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, duration));

  const startWork = async () => {
    const tasks = [wait(100), wait(200), wait(300), wait(400), wait(500)];

    setState({ ...state, progress: 0, total: tasks.length });

    for (const task of tasks) {
      // stop if cancelled
      //   if (state.total === 0) return;

      const data = await task();

      setState({ ...state, progress: state.progress + 1 });
    }
  };

  const cancelWork = () => {
    setState({ ...state, total: 0 });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        {state.progress} / {state.total}
      </p>
      <button onClick={startWork}>Start</button>
      <button onClick={cancelWork}>Cancel</button>
    </div>
  );
}



Take advantage of the fact that setState also accepts a function which references the current value of the state, instead of the value of state at render:
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";

export default function ({}) {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ progress: 0, total: 0 });
  const cancelled = useRef(false);

  const wait = (duration) => () => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, duration));

  const startWork = async () => {
    cancelled.current = false; // make sure we always start in a good state
    const tasks = [wait(100), wait(200), wait(300), wait(400), wait(500)];

    setState({ ...state, progress: 0, total: tasks.length });

    for (const task of tasks) {
      // refs are mutated, so future renders to cancel will resolve the issue
      if (cancelled.current) return;

      const data = await task();

      // update to reference current value of the state instead of value of state at render
      setState(curState => ({ ...curState, progress: curState.progress + 1 })); 
    }
  };

  const cancelWork = () => {
    // set cancelled and reset state
    cancelled.current = true;
    setState({ ...state, total: 0, progress: 0 });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        {state.progress} / {state.total}
      </p>
      <button onClick={startWork}>Start</button>
      <button onClick={cancelWork}>Cancel</button>
    </div>
  );
}


Thank you very much. Have you any thoughts on how the cancel button could be done?

@Jurakin I've updated the answer with a potential solution, i haven't tested it but let me know if that works for you.

setState updates the state on the next render.  When you do
setState({ ...state, progress: 0, total: tasks.length });
for (const task of tasks) {
  setState({ ...state, progress: state.progress + 1 });
}

state.progress will be the initial value every iteration of the loop, because it hasn't re-rendered yet, so each time you will be setting it to 0 + 1 (assuming state.progress was initially 0).
What you probably want to do is:
let progress = state.progress || 0;
setState({ ...state, progress, total: tasks.length });
for (const task of tasks) {
    progress += 1;
    setState({ ...state, progress });
}

so that each time you call setState, you are working with the correct value of progress.

I updated my code with let myState = { progress: 0, total: tasks.length };,       myState.progress += 1; setState({ ...state, ...myState }); and its counting. Thank you. You said the state will be the initial value at each iteration, but I see that the value is increasing so it had to be re-rendered.

Any thoughts on how the cancel button could be done?
